How do I get the annotation for header and image done correctly?
In my python code I have added function process_docx to annotate header and paragraphs and also one more function annotate_images to annotate images.
I find a problem in the output doc that header (annotated in yellow) isn't getting annotated and images (should be annotated in light blue) isn't getting annotated. Only the paragraphs are annotated in grey.
In the input word document, I had added 1 header using insert header settings, 2 paragraphs and 1 image that was taken from web. In the output word document, only the paragraphs are getting annotated.
Here's the input document I had used.
Here's the output document.
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import RGBColor
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

def annotate_images(doc):
    for rel in doc.part.rels.values():
        if "image" in rel.target_ref:
            image = rel.target_part
            for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
                for elem in paragraph._element.iter():
                    if elem.tag.endswith('}inline'):
                        if elem.attrib.get(qn('r:embed')) == rel.rel_id:    
                            set_paragraph_bg_color(paragraph, 'ADD8E6') # light blue
                            break

def process_docx(input_path, output_path):
    doc = Document(input_path)

    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'):
            set_paragraph_bg_color(paragraph, 'FFFF00') # Yellow
        elif paragraph.text.strip(): #Ensures non-empty paragraphs
            set_paragraph_bg_color(paragraph, 'D3D3D3') # Light grey

    annotate_images(doc)
    
    doc.save(output_path)

I'll provide the whole code if you guys didn't understand. I see there is a sitewide rule for minimal, reproducible example hence I asked my problem concisely. I also asked this question in codeproject but to no avail.
I couldn't do anything much about the header and for the image annotation I tried this code by adding hashing technique but it didn't work.
import hashlib

def annotate_images(doc):
    for rel in doc.part.rels.values():
        if "image" in rel.target_ref:
            image = rel.target_part
            image_hash = hashlib.sha256(image.blob).hexdigest()
            for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
                paragraph_text_hash = hashlib.sha256(paragraph.text.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
                if image_hash == paragraph_text_hash:
                    annotate_paragraph(paragraph, 'ADD8E6')


Don’t use pictures for the word document, or do you assume we will type your word for a reproduceable example. Could you not better use LaTex instead Word?

Do a preliminary debugging and post a minimal reproducible example including a sample file and debugging details.

Why are you modifying the document?  The modifications are adding a grey highlight to the paragraphs.  There is no reason you should be changing document if you want exactly the same doc.

@jdweng That's the purpose of my task. I'm highlighting to show which is what in the document or in other words I'm annotating the document. I've solved the header part and added yellow highlighting but I'm yet to know how to highlight the image.

@Hermann12 I'm planning to throw images but it will make my project task incomplete. I have no problem with not adding images otherwise. I chose Word since using images and PDF I'll have to use same python-docx library that requires word document to edit.

I've worked out my problem guys. Thanks for your responses especially @Hermann12

@sdd3242 My comment about images was not related to your word document, it was related to you question.

I've identified the fault in headers and images to not annotate was in the methods I used to place each of them in the word document.
For headers it was to simply select heading from style section and for images you had to add it by clicking on pictures in insert > illustrations > pictures. I've finished the code and in it also added equation annotation.
Here's the entire code and also IO snaps. I hope this helps anyone who has document annotation problems in future.
Input Document
Output Document
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import RGBColor
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

def set_paragraph_bg_color(paragraph, color_hex): #Function which adds background colors
    shading_elm = OxmlElement('w:shd')
    shading_elm.set(qn('w:val'), 'clear')
    shading_elm.set(qn('w:color'), 'auto')
    shading_elm.set(qn('w:fill'), color_hex)
    paragraph._element.get_or_add_pPr().append(shading_elm)

def insert_label(paragraph, label): #Labelling on top of the doc element
    label_run = paragraph.insert_paragraph_before().add_run(f'[{label}]')
    label_run.bold = True
    label_run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00)

def annotate_images(doc):
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                if run.element.xpath('.//w:drawing') or run.element.xpath('.//w:pict'):
                    insert_label(paragraph, 'This is an image')
                    set_paragraph_bg_color(paragraph, 'ADD8E6')  #Light blue for paragraphs

def process_docx(input_path, output_path): #for heading, equation and paragraphs
    try:
        doc = Document(input_path)

        for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
            if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'):
                insert_label(paragraph, 'This is a Header')
                set_paragraph_bg_color(paragraph, 'FFFF00') # Yellow for headers
            elif "Equation:" in paragraph.text:
                insert_label(paragraph, 'This is an Equation')
                set_paragraph_bg_color(paragraph, '00FF00')
            elif paragraph.text.strip(): #Ensures non-empty paragraphs
                insert_label(paragraph, 'This is a Paragraph')
                set_paragraph_bg_color(paragraph, 'D3D3D3') # Light grey for paragraphs
            
        for table in doc.tables:
            for row in table.rows:
                for cell in row.cells:
                    for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                        if paragraph.text.strip():
                            set_paragraph_bg_color(paragraph, 'FFFFFF') #White for paragraph gaps

        annotate_images(doc)

        doc.save(output_path)
        print(f"Annotated Document saved to {output_path}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing document: {e}")
    

input_path = 'C://Users//Arnav//Desktop//Document annotate tool//MILKY_WAY.docx'
output_path = 'annotated_document.docx'

process_docx(input_path, output_path)


SO has its own dedicated image server. For the sake of permanence, please consider adding your example images using the "Image" button on the edit toolbars. Thanks.

@LTyrone Sure. I'll change that once I'm back from work. :D
